# Evaluating $\int\frac{\cos(\frac{1}{x})}{x^2}\operatorname dx$?

Tags: trigonometry

I have my weak spot in integral and derivative of trig stuff . I just don't understand how they interact with the normal integral and derivatives.

whats  $$\int\frac{\cos(\frac{1}{x})}{x^2}\operatorname dx$$ ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Substitute $u = \frac 1 x$; then $du = -\frac 1 {x^2} dx$ and write

$$\int \frac{\cos\frac 1 x}{x^2} dx = -\int \cos \frac 1 x \left(- \frac{dx}{x^2} \right)$$

Comment: In general, if you have a difficult function $f$ and a simpler one $g$, and your integrand has $f(g(x))$, make the substitution $u = g(x)$.